# How to use two different database in one app?

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-messaging, microservices

Just asking, how to use two different databases (`mysql`, `mongodb`) in one app.

I have created two micro-services

1. Authentication service
2. Messaging service for my chat app.

The authentication is done in `node.js` mongo
The messaging service in `php` and `mysql` using `FCM`.

At the moment i have two different android app
One authenticate user and the other send messaging with push notification.

Both information are stored in their own respective database.

How do i coming the two of them and allowing the `mongodb` to store user info only with `GCM` reg token and `mysql` to store chat rooms and channel.

If this question is kinda vague let me know, I will narrow it down.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the middleware to authenticate the users from your MongoDB and once the user is authenticated you can generate the oAuth token. This token can be used for referencing the chat related data in your MySql database. All service calls to MySql database should be passed via oAuth middleware to check for valid token and then do the next messaging process.

Comment: at the moment i have two differn apps one authenticate users with node.js mongo db with jwt and that working.

Comment: user can login/register and see his profile, and the app is to send /recieve messaging using gcm/fcm and the info is stored in mysql. how do i connect php/msql and node.js/mongodb.